# How to compare BigDecimal, but approximately?

Tags: java, android

I have this code:

```
BigDecimal d = ...;
if (d.compareTo(Expression.PI) == 0) {
    //do something
}
```

where Expression.PI is pi rounded to 100th decimal.

But I don't need to compare if d is equal to pi with up to 100 decimals, but only let's say up to 20th decimal. To put it other way, how to check if d is approximately equal to pi?

I tried

```
Expression.PI.setScale(20, RoundingMode.HALF_UP).compareTo(d.setScale(20, RoundingMode.HALF_UP)) == 0;
```

and

```
Expression.PI.setScale(20, RoundingMode.HALF_UP).compareTo(d) == 0;
```

But none of these two seem to work. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you provide an example of numbers that you expect to work, but that aren't working as you expect?

Comment: Well for example, if I have number that is pi rounded to 20 decimals. That wouldn't work because Expression.PI is rounded to 100 decimals.

Comment: So you're sure you have `d` equal to **exactly** pi rounded to 20 places? For one thing, it is hard to believe you need that much precision. You could try rounding to, say 5 places and see what happens.

Comment: It was just an example to clarify the question. And the question way not how much precision I need. Anyway, it really isn't important, the way to do this is important. Once I find out how to do this, I can simply change precision.

Comment: But I'm pretty sure what you have **is** the way to do this. That's why I'm curious about the exact values you have tried.

Comment: Hmm. Then the problem might be somewhere else in my code. Thank you

Answer (score 6):

As lucasvw mentioned in the comments, I think you're already doing it correctly and there must be a problem with your 'd' value. Here is a test class that shows the correct result.

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.RoundingMode;

public class BigDecimalTest {

public static void main(String args[]) {
    BigDecimal PI = new BigDecimal("3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419");
    BigDecimal otherValue = new BigDecimal("3.14159");

    boolean test = PI.setScale(5, RoundingMode.HALF_UP).compareTo(otherValue) == 0;

    System.out.println("compareTo: " + test);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static final boolean isWithinTolerance(final BigDecimal bigDecimal1, final BigDecimal bigDecimal2, final BigDecimal tolerance)
{
    if (bigDecimal1 == null || bigDecimal2 == null || tolerance == null)
    {
        return false;
    }

    final BigDecimal diff = bigDecimal1.abs().subtract(bigDecimal2.abs()).abs();

    return diff.compareTo(tolerance) < 0;
}
```